# Databind UserControl to Collection

Tags: winforms, data-binding, user-controls

I'm trying to create a user control that I can databind to a collection (an EntityCollection to be specific).  All I want is to be able to set a property, such as:

```
MyControl.DataSource = Order.Items
```

Then, I want my control to be able to detect when entities are added or removed from the Order.Items collection.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Look at BindingList<> - it can do what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm trying BindingList<>, but when I create a new BindingList<>(Order.Items.ToList()), and update the source EntityCollection, the binding list does not get updated.